# Qmunicate - Android voice / video call doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, android, ios, quickblox

I am using the android sdk of qmunicate. I can call just fine between android and android but if I want to call to web or to IOS it just don't come through. In the IOS log I can see that someone is calling or at least connecting but it won't come through on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

We recommend you to download the latest version of Android WebRTC SDK (2.2.6) as it has most audio and video calling issues fixed.

You can download it and check out the framework changelog here:
http://quickblox.com/developers/Android#Framework_changelog